# How to check if application is running as administrator VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, admin, vb.net-2010

I have made an application and some of its features only work with admin rights,

How can I check if application is running with admin rights or not ?

- And show a message box if application is not running with admin rights to run as administrator.

Answer (score 16):

```
Imports System.Security.Principal

Dim identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
Dim principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity)
Dim isElevated as Boolean = principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator) 
If isElevated Then
  MessageBox.Show("Is Admin")
End If
```

In VB.Net there is even a shortcut for this:

```
If My.User.IsInRole(ApplicationServices.BuiltInRole.Administrat‌​or) Then ...
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  It answers the OP's question, and I tested the solution and it works perfectly.

Comment: Something is wrong in Windows 10 with this code, all the users are reported like administrators, even Guests without Administrator role

Answer (score 3):

Just change the app.manifest to force require administration:

**Solution Explorer --> My Project --> View Windows Settings**

`<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`

Comment: Downvoted.  Doesn't answer/address the specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and create a file on the system drive inside a try/catch block, and if it catches an access denied exception, then that means that the app is not running as administrator.

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            File.Create("c://test.txt")
            MessageBox.Show("Is Admin")
            File.Delete("c://test.txt")
        Catch ex As Exception
            If ex.ToString.Contains("denied") Then
                MessageBox.Show("Is Not Admin")
            End If
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Too much lame answer. I got it in my mind, too. But it's definitely not for production environment.

Comment: Tricky but not proper answer,
Use HKLM instead of C drive

Comment: Great answer.  I love creativity like this.

Comment: @SixSigmaGuy Thank you, yes me too and now that I'm looking at it after 6 years, it's kinda flabbergasted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A version for **C# 6** (or later), adapted from the *Visual Basic* solution posted elsewhere on this page. In the interest of general-purpose use<sup>1</sup>, here I conceive a `bool`-valued static property**:**

(`using System.Security.Principal;`)

```
public static bool IsAdministrator =>
    new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
            .IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
```

Now having shown this, one must acknowledge that @Mederic's approach does indeed seem superior, since it's unclear precisely what an app might helpfully do after presumably detecting—and reporting—that such a (presumably) critical precondition has failed. Surely it's wiser—and safer—to delegate concerns of this nature to the OS.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> That is, eliding the "`MessageBox`" desiderata articulated by the OP.</sub>